# Accessing the MOngoDB through C# driver in a Medium trust environment

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I've searched for a while and I got no answers so far, my problem relies on the call of this method CreateMongoCRCredential(MongoDb c# driver)

`MongoClientSettings settings = new MongoClientSettings();
                settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress(host, 35428);
                MongoCredential cred = MongoCredential.CreateMongoCRCredential(dbName, user, pwd);
                settings.Credentials = new List<MongoCredential>() { cred };
                Client = new MongoClient(settings);`

Exception:

`Security Exception

Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[SecurityException: Request failed.]
   Agenda.Core.MongoDB.Wrapper.DbContext.GetContext(String host, String user, String pwd, String dbName, Boolean forceReset) in DbContext.cs:80`

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Medium Trust is not supported. Currently, version 1.x supports partial trust. However, we will be dropping partial trust support in our 2.x release. See this JIRA ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-952.